# how to make sure one process start before other process?

Tags: python, asynchronous, process, multiprocessing

How can I make shure that one process starts before the other?

**Background:** I am doing computations in two separate processes (each of them running in a loop). But for the computations in one process I need the results from the computations of the other process. The first thought might be: *why not do it synchronous?* But this one calculation runs faster than the other one. And if there are no new results available, it should just continue with the last available value.

**Example Code:**

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import time
import random

queue = Queue()

def some_calculation():
    # this is slower
    time.sleep(2)
    return random.randint(0, 10)

def some_other_calculation(required):
    # this is faster
    time.sleep(0.5)
    return required + random.randint(0, 10)

def first_target(queue):
    while True:
        # doing some computations
        res = some_calculation()
        queue.put(res)

def second_target(queue):
    res_list= []
    # req = 5 as an initial guess might also work, but lets
    # assume this is not an option
    while True:
        try:
            req = queue.get(block=False)
        except:
            print('no new value available, reuse old value')
        res = some_other_calculation(req)
        res_list.append(res)
        print('results so far:', res_list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    proc1 = Process(target=first_target, args=(queue,))
    proc2 = Process(target=second_target, args=(queue,))
    proc1.start()
    # time.sleep(3) here everything works fine, but is there
    # maybe a more elegant solution?
    proc2.start()
```

Is there a way -- aside from just sleeping or predefining a value for `req` -- to make sure, that this one process really starts before the other one does?

Many thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is for `second_target` to start a thread that will issue blocking `get` calls on the queue and thus will constantly update the `req` variable with the latest value available. `second_target` also needs to make an initial synchronous call to `some_calculation` to get its initial value of `req` in order to greatly simplify the logic. I have also replace the infinite `while True` loop in `second_target` with a more limited loop for demo purposes in order that the program terminates:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import time
import random
from threading import Thread


def some_calculation():
    # this is slower
    time.sleep(2)
    return random.randint(0, 10)

def some_other_calculation(required):
    # this is faster
    time.sleep(0.5)
    return required + random.randint(0, 10)

def first_target(queue):
    while True:
        # doing some computations
        res = some_calculation()
        queue.put(res)

def second_target(queue):
    def monitor_queue():
        nonlocal queue, req
        while True:
            req = queue.get()

    res_list= []
    req = some_calculation() # Call it synchronously for initial value
    last_req = req
    Thread(target=monitor_queue, daemon=True).start()
    for _ in range(10): # for testing purposes so we terminate:
    #while True:
        if req == last_req:
            print('no new value available, reuse old value')
        else:
            print('got a new value')
            last_req = req
        res = some_other_calculation(req)
        res_list.append(res)
        print('results so far:', res_list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    queue = Queue()
    p = Process(target=first_target, args=(queue,), daemon=True)
    p.start()
    second_target(queue)
```

Prints:

```
no new value available, reuse old value
results so far: [5]
got a new value
results so far: [5, 2]
no new value available, reuse old value
results so far: [5, 2, 2]
no new value available, reuse old value
results so far: [5, 2, 2, 7]
no new value available, reuse old value
results so far: [5, 2, 2, 7, 11]
got a new value
results so far: [5, 2, 2, 7, 11, 11]
no new value available, reuse old value
results so far: [5, 2, 2, 7, 11, 11, 13]
no new value available, reuse old value
results so far: [5, 2, 2, 7, 11, 11, 13, 13]
got a new value
results so far: [5, 2, 2, 7, 11, 11, 13, 13, 7]
no new value available, reuse old value
results so far: [5, 2, 2, 7, 11, 11, 13, 13, 7, 11]
```